# What is the correct way to use NetUserGetLocalGroups?

Tags: windows, winapi

My application needs to get the local groups of a given account in the form of **DOMAIN_NAME\USER_NAME**

And I want to use the NetUserGetLocalGroups API, which is documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetlocalgroups

The "servername" parameter is defined like this:

> A pointer to a constant string that specifies the DNS or NetBIOS name
> of the remote server on which the function is to execute. If this
> parameter is NULL, the local computer is used.

What does "remote server" mean in this case? Is it a Domain Controller of the DOMAIN_NAME?

If yes, then I need to find the domain controller first?

Comment: Local groups are the *non* domain groups - they're groups created and configured on individual (non Domain Controller) computers. If you're interested in Local groups, Domain Controllers are irrelevant. If you're interested in Domain groups, you've settled on the wrong function.

Comment: So, this API is to get the "Local Groups" which are created/configured in the "servername", in which the "username" has membership?

Comment: you need query local *SAM* database. so pass 0 in first argument. so called *LocalGroups* really *Aliases* in sam terminology

Comment: so to speak - *DOMAIN_NAME\USER_NAME* in which (computer) *SAM* database ? are *USER_NAME* local user account ? if yes - pass 0 for use  local computer. if *USER_NAME* some account in domain, may be not on local comp known - pass name of domain server in first parameter

Comment: @RbMm but, I could add a domain user as member of a server local group. In this case, the servername=NULL and username=domain\user. This can only be executed in the servername. That would give list of local groups created in servername where domain\user has membership. Then change the servername to a remote-server name for checking in other server, correct?

Comment: but on which computer you want query this ? on every computer exist *SAM* database. the first parameter *DNS or NetBIOS name* used in call *SamConnect* for open concrete *SAM*, then all query (final is *SamGetAliasMembership* ) used open database. of course in case domain, may be different result if query local *SAM* and *SAM* on DC

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just tested, calling the API with servername=domain_controller and I get list of "Domain Local Group".

Comment: @RbMm Ok, so the API will query the SAM database which reside on the servername parameter. And I found that the API also returns Domain Local Groups where the username has membership. In that case, I put domain controller as servername parameter.

Comment: yes in general. you can use DC DNS or NetBIOS name in first argument for query. depend from what is your target. for what this need at all